# How can I wrap NSView in SwiftUI macOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a NSView wrapper, I made this code so far:

```swift
struct NSViewWrapper: View {
    let nsView: NSView
    var body: some View {
        NSHostingView(rootView: nsView)
    }
}
```

I tried this code but Xcode say:

Return type of property 'body' requires that 'NSHostingView' conform to 'View'

Generic class 'NSHostingView' requires that 'NSView' conform to 'View'

Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'NSHostingView' conform to 'View'

How can make this wrapper works and solving the issues?

I updated my code to:

```swift
struct nsViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSView
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Error: Missing return in instance method expected to return 'NSView'

Comment: `NSHostingView` is the opposite of what you're looking for. From the first line [of the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview): "You use NSHostingView objects to integrate SwiftUI views into your AppKit view hierarchies". What you're looking for is [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable). I'd suggest looking up a tutorial on it.

Comment: NSViewRepresentable is what you need

Comment: @Alexander UI prefix usually refers to iOS only, NS is macOS

Comment: For the `Missing return in instance method expected to return 'NSView'` error, `func makeNSView` needs to return an `NSView`.

Comment: Ooops, that's what I meant, at this point default to thinking I'm the only one programming for macOS and that all the questions here are for iOS haha